# Problem converting Java Application to Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, japplet

I am trying to convert a **working** simple Java application to an applet. The application consists of a main.java and a gooey.java

> **Main.java**

```
package hellow_convert;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
public class main extends JApplet {
public static void main(String[] args) {
gooey gui = new gooey();    
}
public void init() 
{ 
gooey gui = new gooey();        
} 
public void stop() {}
}
```

> **gooey.java**

```
package hellow_convert;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class gooey {    
public  JFrame f = new JFrame();
private JPanel pnlNorth = new JPanel(); 
private JButton btnNorth = new JButton("North");
private JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar(); // MenuBar
private JMenu mnuFile = new JMenu("File"); // File Entry on Menu bar
private JMenuItem mnuItemAbout = new JMenuItem("About"); // About Entry
public gooey(){
f.setJMenuBar(mb);
mb.add(mnuFile);       
mb.add(mnuHelp);
pnlNorth.add(btnNorth);
f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
f.getContentPane().add(pnlNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
f.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 100);
}
}
```

It looks like this.
[image: Applet]
I just cant seem to make it run as an applet. When I run it in debug, an applet window opens, and then, the JFrame window pops up (just as in the application). As an application, it runs as expected, but how do I get controls into the Applet window?
I'm new to this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "I am trying to convert a working simple Java application to an applet"  For a better user experience, & lower maintenance costs, launch the frame directly from a web page using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: @Andrew Thanks! Would it require any client-side app installation?

Comment: It would require a working Java installation with Webstart of at least the version you require. Note that two years ago some 64-bit JREs didn't provide Webstart, but I'm not sure if that's still relevant.

Comment: *"Would it **(JWS)** require any client-side app installation?"* Short answer, no.  Long answer, nope.  JWS has been co-bundled with the JRE since around 1.4.  JWS is intended as the 'one click' installation option for Java rich clients.  Here is a very simplistic [example](http://pscode.org/jws/basicserv.jnlp) from my [JWS API examples](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#bs) page.  Also make sure you follow my earlier link to the info. tag for JWS.  It has lots of informative links relating to JWS deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, JApplet is a Swing container itself and thus you'd have to use the applet's content pane in your class `gooey`, instead of always using a JFrame (which is a desktop window and wouldn't not work with an applet).

Try and pass either the JApplet or the JFrame to the `gooey()` constructor, instead of creating the JFrame in that class.

Edit: your constructor might look like this:

```
public gooey(RootPaneContainer c){
  c.getRootPane().setJMenuBar(mb);
  mb.add(mnuFile);       
  mb.add(mnuHelp);
  pnlNorth.add(btnNorth);
  c.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  c.getContentPane().add(pnlNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

}

Then call it like:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame(...);
new gooey(f);
```

or

```
JApplet a = new JApplet(...);        
new gooey(a);
```

you could also do this in your main class, since it is already an applet instance

```
new gooey(this);
```

The `setBounds(...)` should only be called when dealing with a JFrame.

Comment: Thanks.. Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: I tried Container c = this; and passed c to gooey. Do i need to perform some typecasting before i can use c.getContentPane()?

Comment: That worked when I did JApplet a = this; Thanks!! (Please edit your answer to reflect the same)

Comment: @anirudh I'm not sure where you did `JApplet a = this;` but I'd say that looks somewhat awkward. I'd rather not update the answer in order to promote slightly better style ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you start by having a look at the Applet tutorial .... applets need to have an init method instead of main (amongst other things) -> http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html

Comment: I do have an init method (please see code). Main is the name of my class. The applet initializes, but the controls open up in a separate JFrame.

Comment: Sorry you are right ... your code is very difficult to read ! I missed it ... essentially the problem is the JFrame your are using ... its a desktop window - not an applet related class.